# Class with 2 methods: generic argument vs primitive argument

Tags: java, generics, primitive, type-erasure

Suppose you have the following Java class:

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    public void myMethod(int idx){...}
    public void myMethod(T idx){...}
}
```

Now if a class user does:

```
MyClass<Integer> ref = new MyClass<>();
ref.myMethod(1); // void myMethod(int idx) gets called
ref.myMethod(new Integer(1)); // void myMethod(T idx) gets called
```

Why does ref.myMethod(1) not call the generic method? Which checks are in place?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you’re right! The generic argument is erased to Object! Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @user16320675 so, when I call myMethod(1), the JVM doesn’t call the generic method because an Object can’t be really cast to an int or what?

Comment: Why is it the best match? Are these “best match” rules or precedence rules written somewhere in the Java documentation?